# Imported function not finding filepath when used in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, path

I have the following folder setup:

```
project
├── pipeline
│   ├── functions.py
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── library
│       └── data.csv
|
└── notebook.ipynb
```

I import my functions.py into the notebook as follows:

```
from pipeline.functions import *
```

In my notebook I use one of the functions that looks like the following:

```
def myfunction(df):
    
    libpath = f'library/data.csv'
    try:
        lib_df = pd.read_csv(libpath)
    except OSError:
        print(f'library not found for given filepath: {libpath}')
        sys.exit()
        
    df = df['molecule'].apply(is_covalent, lib_df)
  
    return df
```

I keep getting a FileNotFoundError for this.

If I try defining the libpath in my notebook and reading it, it works fine.

I have checked i'm in the right directory with `os.getcwd()` and the pathing is correct.
I've also tried different path formats:

```
libpath = f'pipeline/library/data.csv'
libpath = f'{os.getcwd()}/pipeline/library/data.csv'
libpath = f'pipeline\\library\\data.csv'
libpath = f'{os.getcwd()}\\pipeline\\library\\data.csv'
```

None of these appear to work.

I have also tried to explicitly import the function I'm using and this doesn't make a difference.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the function `myfunction` is in the `pipeline/functions` script you could use os combined with the `__file__` variable to get the correct path as follows.

```py
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
libpath = os.path.join(script_dir, 'library', 'data.csv')
```

If the function is in the jupyter notebook your `libpath` should be like this:

```py
libpath = os.path.join(script_dir, 'pipeline', 'library', 'data.csv')
```

Using the `__file__` attribute ensures that the path is always relative to the script and not the current directory where you are axecuting the script from.
Using `os.path.join` makes sure you have the correct directory separator for your OS (`/` or `\`).